# Ruby make instance method or class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this function

```
 def get_free_downloads(kdp_report)
    #return 0 if no free reports found
    return (kdp_report.presence and kdp_report.transaction_type == 'Free - Promotion') ? kdp_report.downloads : 0
  end
```

I want to move it to model

What will be better and more readable and more rails way?

1)

```
class KdpReport < activeRecord::Base
  def self.get_free_downloads(kdp_report)
        return (kdp_report.presence and kdp_report.transaction_type == 'Free - Promotion') ? kdp_report.downloads : 0
   end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
free_downloads = KdpReport.get_free_downloads kdp_report
```

2)

Or make it like this:

```
 class KdpReport < activeRecord::Base
      def get_free_downloads
            return transaction_type == 'Free - Promotion') ? downloads : 0
       end
    end
```

And use like this:

```
free_downloads = kdp_report.presence ? kdp_report.get_free_downloads : 0
```

Comment: This would be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but it seems to me to be more of a matter of how you want to use it. Do you want it as a property of your KdpReport, or as a functional utility? Personally, I'd probably go with an instance method of the model.

Comment: Is it `presence` an attribute?